# Header (select all) checkbox does not stay checked

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin, vaadin8

we are using Vaadin 8 and we have a multi select grid. In the header there is a checkbox present which acts as a select / deselect all checkbox. The problem is that the header checkbox does not stay checked after the window is closed. E.g. if the window is opened, the header checkbox is checked -> all other checkboxes are checked, the window is then closed and opened again he header checkbox is unchecked again. Is there a method to manually set the header checkbox value, or any other workaround? We work with a data provider object and upon the button click the selected items are saved, but we have no way of accessing (or we do not know of a way of accessing) the header checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Select All checkbox state is determined through [MultiSelectionModelState.allSelected](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/vaadin/shared/ui/grid/MultiSelectionModelState.java#L30). You can access the model via

```
MultiSelectionModelImpl<MyPojo> selectionModel = (MultiSelectionModelImpl<MyPojo>) grid.getSelectionModel();
```

(or using the return value when you set the selection mode).

You can mark the checkbox selected via

```
selectionModel.selectAll();
```

or deselected via

```
selectionModel.deselectAll();
```